# ACF: Can't get title from Relation-field Post object within Post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to set up a custom column inside my admin pages using a ACF-field. The field is a relationship field, however I keep getting errors.
My code inside functions.php:

```
function my_product_columns($columns)
{
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'     => 'Name',
        'artist'    => 'Artist',
        'media'     =>  'Media',
    );
    return $columns;
}

function my_product_artist_columns($column)
{
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ($column == 'artist') {
                $artist_field = get_field( "product_artist", $post_id);
                echo $artist_field->post_title; //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
        }
        else {
             echo '';
        }
}
```

With this I get the following error message:

> Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in

If I do `echo $artist_field['post_title'];` I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in

And the `print_r($artist_field);` gives me:
WP_Post Object

```
 WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 778
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2018-12-06 09:18:26
        [post_date_gmt] => 2018-12-06 09:18:26
        [post_content] => This is Solomon
        [post_title] => Solomon Northup
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => solomon-northup
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2018-12-06 09:18:26
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-12-06 09:18:26
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://localhost:8888/swart.shop/wp/?post_type=artists&p=778
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => artists
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

Is it because it is a post-loop within a post-loop and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/use-post-object-in-a-loop-of-a-custom-post-type/

my code is then:

```
if ($column == 'artist') {
            $post_object = get_field( "product_artist"); if( $post_object ) {   
            $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post );  //Call the post object Inside and work with
            the_title();
            $post = $post_id; setup_postdata( $post ); ////Call back the "parent" post datas
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
    }
    else {
         echo '';
    }
```